# Java Map<Integer,List<Object>> doesn't hold previous data

Tags: java, swing, list, dictionary

(I am not sure for the title, as I don't know how to express clearly what I figured out).

I have a JTable. Every time user wants to alter some of its data, I want to hold the old data in a List. Then I want to make some sql update stuff, so I want to know the exact row that changes took place. Thus I decided to create a Map with the specific row as a key and the list with the old data ( Map> ).

Below there is my code

```
public class MapListsInJtable extends JFrame{
  private final Object[][] rowdata = { {"one",1}, {"two",2}, {"three",3}};
  private final Object[] colnames = {"col1", "col2", "col3"};
  private final List<Object> oldValues; //for updated list
  private final Map<Integer,List<Object>> updatedList;
  private DefaultTableModel model;
  private JTable table;
  private JScrollPane scrollPane;

  public MapListsInJtable(){
    this.updatedList = new Hashtable<>();
    this.oldValues = new ArrayList<>();
    initializeTable();
  }

  private void initializeTable(){
    model = new DefaultTableModel(rowdata,colnames);
    table = new JTable(model){

        @Override
        public void changeSelection(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean toggle, boolean extend) {
            super.changeSelection(rowIndex, columnIndex, toggle, extend);
            if(toggle){
                //user gathers rows in order to delete them by holding ctrl
                System.out.println("toggling...");
                for(int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++)
                    oldValues.add(table.getValueAt(rowIndex, i));
            }
            else{
                //user presses left mouse button and selects multiple rows
                if(extend){
                    System.out.println("extends...");
                    for(int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++)
                        oldValues.add(table.getValueAt(rowIndex, i));
                }
                else{
                    oldValues.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    //to see if there has been change in table data
    ListSelectionHandler handler = new ListSelectionHandler(this);
    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(handler);

    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    //resize columns and use horizontal scroll bar to view data
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    //disable column dragging
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
}

protected DefaultTableModel getModel(){return model;}
public JTable getTable(){return table;}
public List<Object> getOldValues(){return this.oldValues;}
public Map<Integer,List<Object>> getUpdatedList(){return this.updatedList;}

public void initializeUI(){
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    setSize(300,150);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}

private class ListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener{
    private final MapListsInJtable m;

    public ListSelectionHandler(MapListsInJtable m){this.m = m;}

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        //in order not valueChanged to be called twice
        boolean hasBeenAdjusted = e.getValueIsAdjusting();
        if(hasBeenAdjusted == true){
            int selectedRow = m.getTable().getSelectedRow();
            //put data in updatedList
            for(int i = 0; i < m.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++)
                m.getOldValues().add(m.getTable().getValueAt(selectedRow, i));
            m.getUpdatedList().put(selectedRow, m.getOldValues());
            System.out.println("updatedList: " + m.getUpdatedList());
          }
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] af){
    MapListsInJtable m = new MapListsInJtable();
    m.initializeUI();
  }
}
```

When I select one row, data are put normally inside updatedList.

**output:**

```
updatedList: {0=[`one, 1, null`]}
```

But when I select another row, I have 2 positions inside updatedList with the data of the new row. All previous data are gone.

**output:**

```
updatedList: {1=[`two, 2, null`], 0=[`two, 2, null`]}
```

Could someone please explain me why is this happening? How am I supposed to fix it? Thank you in advance

Comment: You'll have to write your own TabelModel (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)  More over, read up on MVC...

Comment: Will TabelModel solve Map problem? In what way?

Comment: Your implemented TableModel will have a data structure that holds your data and handles changes to your table.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code is the problem:

```
  int selectedRow = m.getTable().getSelectedRow();
                //put data in updatedList
                for(int i = 0; i < m.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++)
                    m.getOldValues().add(m.getTable().getValueAt(selectedRow, i));
                m.getUpdatedList().put(selectedRow, m.getOldValues());
                System.out.println("updatedList: " + m.getUpdatedList());
              }
```

so, try this:

```
  int selectedRow = m.getTable().getSelectedRow();
                //put data in updatedList
                for(int i = 0; i < m.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++)
                m.getOldValues().add(m.getTable().getValueAt(selectedRow, i));
                List oldvalue = ((List) ((ArrayList) m.getOldValues()).clone());
                m.getUpdatedList().put(selectedRow, oldvalue);
                System.out.println("updatedList: " + m.getUpdatedList());
              }
```

Comment: so you say not to put for-loop? And what will I have in column position in `m.getOldValues().add(m.getTable().getValueAt(selectedRow, i));` i is the column iterator

Comment: updateList is a Map and it doesn't let me use `add`. Only `put`

Comment: yeah now it worked! Thank you so much! You are my saviour for today!! :-)